# XSLT - Adding a sequence number/counter to an element while copying all other elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, edi, xslt-3.0

Dears,
I have below xml its an edi xml having 2 documents inside. I would like to assign a sequence number for each ST and SE under M_810
I have 2 M_810 for my First M_810 - ST-D_329 and SE-D-329 - I want to have sequence number 2001
Second M_810 - ST-D_329 and SE-D_329 - I want to have sequence number 2002

I have tried below code . its always giving me the 2001 at the required places. Looking for some help on fixing this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="D_329">
<xsl:if test="((../name() = 'S_ST') or (../name() = 'S_SE'))">
<D_329><xsl:value-of select="2000 + ../position()"/></D_329>    
</xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

src xml:

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Interchange>
        <M_810>
                <S_ST>
                    <D_143>810</D_143>
                    <D_329>47857</D_329>
                </S_ST>
                <S_BIG>
                    <D_373>20210128</D_373>
                    <D_76>917183</D_76>
                    <D_373_2>20210120</D_373_2>
                    <D_324>13453796</D_324>
                </S_BIG>
                <S_SE>
                    <D_96>21</D_96>
                    <D_329>47857</D_329>
                </S_SE>
            </M_810>                
            <M_810>
                <S_ST>
                    <D_143>810</D_143>
                    <D_329>47858</D_329>
                </S_ST>
                <S_BIG>
                    <D_373>20210128</D_373>
                    <D_76>917184</D_76>
                    <D_373_2>20210120</D_373_2>
                    <D_324>13453797</D_324>
                </S_BIG>
                <S_SE>
                    <D_96>21</D_96>
                    <D_329>47858</D_329>
                </S_SE>
            </M_810>
        </Interchange>
```

Required output:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Interchange>
        <M_810>
                <S_ST>
                    <D_143>810</D_143>
                    <D_329>2001</D_329>
                </S_ST>
                <S_BIG>
                    <D_373>20210128</D_373>
                    <D_76>917183</D_76>
                    <D_373_2>20210120</D_373_2>
                    <D_324>13453796</D_324>
                </S_BIG>
                <S_SE>
                    <D_96>21</D_96>
                    <D_329>2001</D_329>
                </S_SE>
            </M_810>                
            <M_810>
                <S_ST>
                    <D_143>810</D_143>
                    <D_329>2002</D_329>
                </S_ST>
                <S_BIG>
                    <D_373>20210128</D_373>
                    <D_76>917184</D_76>
                    <D_373_2>20210120</D_373_2>
                    <D_324>13453797</D_324>
                </S_BIG>
                <S_SE>
                    <D_96>21</D_96>
                    <D_329>2002</D_329>
                </S_SE>
            </M_810>
         </Interchange>
```

xml nodes to be modified for each occurrence in the parent:

```
  <S_ST>
    <D_143>810</D_143> 
    <D_329>47857</D_329> >> <D_329>2001</D_329>
</S_ST>
and 
    <S_SE>
      <D_96>21</D_96>
      <D_329>47857</D_329> >> <D_329>2001</D_329>
    </S_SE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 3, it sounds as if you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="M_810/S_ST/D_329">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number count="M_810/S_ST/D_329" start-at="2001" level="any"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="M_810/S_SE/D_329">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:number count="M_810/S_SE/D_329" start-at="2001" level="any"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't quite been able to check the right output, check yourself or if it doesn't work consider to cut irrelevant elements from the samples to ease our task to see the elements you want to transform and number.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the quick help. It works for me . The expected output is matching. I have updated the xml sample to ease for others. Actually I wanted to give full context of the problem.

Comment: Can you please help me on counting no of  segments under M_810 and update at <S_SE>
                    <D_96> all the segments count under M_810 </D_96> thank you

Comment: Hi Martin,
the following gives me the expected result.
<xsl:template match="M_810/S_SE/D_96">      
   <D_96><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/></D_96>   
  </xsl:template>
Please suggest if we can use this syntax . Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @SreenivasReddy, consider to ask new questions in a separate, new question, not in a comment. I have not quite understood what you consider the number of segments but if the solution `<xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>` works for you then it is certainly a way to count nodes. In the spirit of the previous examples with the dedicated `xsl:number` instruction it might also be possible to use `<xsl:template match="M_810/S_SE/D_96"><xsl:copy><xsl:number count="M_810/*"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin ,
I would certainly post a new question . Thanks a lot for your help again.
Cheers.